# Can't deploy rails application to heroku for the first time; ignoring manifest.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Rails application onto heroku for the first time. I'm using Rails 3.2.11 and ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 8. I've been searching a long time for my answer, but have been unsuccessful. I've followed [heroku's tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3#prerequisites) on getting started all the way until it tells you to push.

```
git push heroku master
```

This gives me the following error:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompile
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins!
Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle
them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/
initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.
rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from at          
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins!  
Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle
them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/
initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.
rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from at     
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/Rakefile:7)
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapte
r.rb:1208:in initialize'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapte
r.rb:1208:innew'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapte
r.rb:1208:in connect'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapte
r.rb:326:ininitialize'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapte
r.rb:28:in new'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapte
r.rb:28:inpostgresql_connection'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_pool.rb:315:in new_connection'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_pool.rb:325:incheckout_new_connection'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_pool.rb:247:in block (2 levels) in checkout'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_pool.rb:242:inloop'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_pool.rb:242:in block in checkout'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_pool.rb:239:incheckout'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_pool.rb:102:in block in connection'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_pool.rb:101:inconnection'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_pool.rb:410:in retrieve_connection'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_specification.rb:171:inretrieve_connection'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connecti
on_specification.rb:145:in connection'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:inclear_cache!'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in block (2 levels) in
<class:Railtie>'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in_run__35780770
63533031320__prepare__2058969196489290367__callbacks'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in __run_callback
'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in_run_prepare_c
allbacks'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in run_callbacks'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:inprepare
!'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in prepare
!'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:inblock in '
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in instance_exec'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:inrun'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in block in run_initializers
'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:ineach'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in run_initializers'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:ininitialize!'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in method_missing'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/config/environment.rb:5:i
n'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in require'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:inblock in re
quire'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/v
gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in load_depend
ency'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:inrequire'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in require_environment!'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:297:inblock (2 levels) in initia
lize_tasks'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in block (2 levels) in <top
(required)>'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:inblock (3 levels) in '
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in invoke_or_reboot_rake_ta
sk'
/tmp/build_7255e9b5-d3d1-4b02-adaf-b98a0f6b4528/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:inblock (2 levels) in '
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
!
! Precompiling assets failed.
!
! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
!     [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp.git'
```

I've also tried precompiling the assests using:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Which generates a manifest.yml file in my public/assests directory. I have committed that file. So, it shouldn't be trying to precompile the files at all as per the tutorials I've seen. Why is it ignoring my manifest.yml file?

Please let me know what I can do. I cannot figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: It actually looks like the DATABASE_URL isn't set correctly, given that the error is in the database connection.  What DATABASE_URL shows when you run 'heroku config'.  Have you set up a database add-on?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran heroku config and got myapp has no config variables. I'm assuming it's because I've never deployed anything to the server previously.

Comment: @PeterGoldstein Beyond the steps taken in the getting started tutorial I haven't done anything more to the database. Are there additional steps I should have taken?

Comment: So you probably want a basic database in place.  On the Heroku website, go to your application and click on add-ons.  Add a Dev level Heroku Postgres database.  It's free.

Comment: Ok. @PeterGoldstein I added the heroku postgres add-on dev edition. I re-ran git push heroku master, but got the exact same output as above.

Comment: Did you run 'heroku config'?  Is there a DATABASE_URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was close.  Thrown off by Rails 3.2.x - I use 4.0.x these days.

From the Heroku docs:

While precompiling assets, in Rails 3.x, you can prevent initializing your application and connecting to the database by ensuring that the following line is in your config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: Ok I should have included that file in my original question. I figured that would be something that someone would think to ask. I've followed the instructions closely and I've already got that line in my code.

Comment: Ok.  I'd double check that for typos, etc.  The problem is definitely that you're connecting to the database during assets precompile.  Now, you may say that assets precompile shouldn't run because of the checked in manifest, but I think it's key to understand why the assets precompile is failing.  And it's clearly failing because of a failed attempt to connect to the database.

Comment: Since I already have that line in my application.rb does that mean heroku is somehow ignoring that line and still trying to connect to the db?

Comment: Yes.  The stack trace makes it clear that the failure occurs when the app attempts to connect to the database during assets precompile.

Comment: You're sure that everything local is committed to the git repository and that you're using the master branch?

Comment: Oh my goodness I realized I wasn't on the master branch! How embarrassing. Thanks so much. That's why my changes weren't showing up. I merged with master and the deployment worked beautifully.